# UITableView works in ios6 but not in ios 5.1 (array count trouble)

Tags: xcode, uitableview, row

This is my code to populate UITableView, very very simple:

file .h

```
@interface ViewController: UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITableView *table;
    NSMutableArray *array1;
    NSString *string1
}
```

file .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", nil];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return array1.count; // <------- here there is the problem with iOS 5.1, also [array1 count]
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 20;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:
                 UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    return cell;
}
```

Well, in iOS 6 (simulator and real device) its all right, UITableView loads and shows all rows of array1 objects; in iOS 5.1 (simulator and real device) it doesnt crash but UITableView is empty, no rows showed (Header and Footer are attached), and I'have noticed this could be a problem with the numberOfRowsInSection: array1.count method, I think in iOS 5.1 it doesnt recognize the right number of rows. Please, what's the best way to write a code compatible with iOS 5.1 and iOS6?

Comment: You shouldn't need to call `reloadData`. Indeed: I've verified your code works verbatim in both iOS 6.0 and 5.1 simulators (with one exception: I had to add a semicolon to the end of the `string1` ivar declaration to get it to compile). I'd suggest deleting your app from the 5.1 simulator, deleting any derived data and doing a clean build. Bonus points if you  change `array1.count` to `[array1 count]` (count isn't a property) :)

Comment: Unluckly 5.1 simulator was clean, when I (re)installed my app. Instead, with [table reloadData] it works also with return array1.count! BTW thanks to have remembered me the way to get bonus point! ;=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After populating the array1 do

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Since I think the data is not available when the tableview is loaded. And this could be different between iOS 5 and 6.

Comment: Fantastic, Roland, I have added simply [table reloadData] and it works fine also in iOS 5.1... but its a "well known" difference between iOS 5 and 6? Its in the developer documentation? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Huxley, I am not sure why this difference is there, it probably has something to do with the rendering and displaying the view.

Comment: Strange - there's no documented difference in the ways tableviews are loaded in iOS 6 vs 5.1 and the example code loads data just fine for me on devices and sims with both versions of the OS. @Huxley: are you sure you don't have other logic that's interfering with the viewDidLoad/ UITableViewDataSource message sequence?

Comment: Maybe because I'm using storyboard and I need to write this code in a UIViewController class linked to "Initial View Controller" with a "Relationship Segue" (mine is a tab bar controlled application, not a single view app): this table is loaded the FIRST time we call this View, and the class has also the methods -(void)awakeFromNib and -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated, not only -(void)viewDidLoad...